# \show for Lua commands

Tags: luatex

TeX (and all newer engines) has the primitive `\show` which helps me probe macros, and most of the time is enough to understand/remember the implementation (rather than having to go back to the source code).

Is there something similar for Lua commands? For instance, Heiko Oberdiek has written replacements for some pdfTeX primitives in LuaTeX, and I'd like to get more information about them using some hypothetical `\showluatexcmd` macro.

```
\input pdftexcmds.sty
\catcode`@=11
\show\pdf@strcmp
%\showluatexcmd{oberdiek.pdftexcmds.strcmp}
\bye
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I seriously doubt that there is something similar for Lua, but you can do the following to find out *where* the function is defined (to get to the source code).

```
\directlua{ require("showluatexcmd") }
\def\showluatexcmd#1{\directlua{showluatexcmd.show(#1)}}

\input pdftexcmds.sty
\catcode`@=11
 \show\pdf@strcmp
\showluatexcmd{oberdiek.pdftexcmds.strcmp}
\bye
```

and the file `showluatexcmd.lua`:

```lua
module(...,package.seeall)

function show( fun )
  local debuginfo = { "source","linedefined","what" }
  for _,v in ipairs(debuginfo) do
    texio.write_nl(string.format("%20s=%q", v, debug.getinfo(fun)[v]))
  end
end
```

One could extend this probably to directly load the function and display it. But in most cases this won't help as there are a lot of functions that are short and call other functions.

A sample output is

```
          source="@/opt/texlive2011/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua"
     linedefined="46"
            what="Lua" )
```

Comment: there is also "lastlinedefined", so you could potentially print a portion of the source file ..

Comment: I was hoping for something similar to Python's `dis` module. Actually, [`luac -l`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872861/lua-equivalent-to-python-dis) may help. Also, what does "what" mean in the debug info?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch a) what is Python's dis module? b) What describes where the function is defined: a "C" function or a "Lua" function (I remember seeing other things written there)

Comment: @Patrick: sorry, the `dis` module is a disassembler: `dis.dis(myfunction)` will print (pseudo-)assembly code for `myfunction`. It seems `luac -l` does that too, but on compiled Lua files (see the well-hidden link in my previous comment), so I'm not sure whether it could be used for LuaTeX.